# App does not ask for permissions on some devices

Tags: java, android, permissions

We have an app, where at some point we want to save a picture.
We implemented Methods to ask for permission.

On my Device (Galaxy S9, news update) it all works fine. It asks for permission and saves the picture. And the device (Galaxy A7) of my gf too.

On other devices, it does not ask for permission and so does not save the picture. I already deleted the app many times to be sure the permissions we're not already given on my phone.

```
addPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(adding.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

                    picintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    picintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picuri);
                    startActivityForResult(picintent, cameracode);
            } else {
                requestStoragePermission();

                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

                picintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                picintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picuri);
                startActivityForResult(picintent, cameracode);



            }} catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kamera nicht unterstützt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



private void requestStoragePermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Berechtigung benötigt")
                .setMessage("Diese Bereichtigunjg wird zum speichern des Bildes benötigt")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(adding.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();

    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}


 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Berechtigung erteilt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Berechtigung nicht erteilt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
};
```

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has nothing to do with `saves the picture`

Comment: If you are reading a image i.e picking from gallery then you need read external storage else if you want to store your image then you need write external storgae permission.

Comment: What Android versions are you running on these devices?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko is right